# Where can I find Nuclear Strike & Fury 3?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, nuclear-strike, fury-3

There are 2 ancient games -- Nuclear Strike and Fury 3. Does anyone know where I can find them to play now?

These games are from around 1997, so I guess they should be able to run in a VM with Windows XP.

I own the original CDs, but they are unreadable now.

They seem to be unavailable on GoG.com, as well.

Comment: A more general form of this question is http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/693/where-to-find-old-games

Comment: If you own a PS3 you can purchase Nuclear Strike off of the Playstation Network for $5.99. Or if you prefer PC you can get it fairly cheap on Amazon, http://www.amazon.com/NUCLEAR-STRIKE-Windows/dp/B00030GNF8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both games do not seem to be Abandon-Ware, at least I can't find them ([Home of the Underdogs](http://www.homeoftheunderdogs.net) does not even list them). And to be honest, it does not surprise me if I look at the company names.

On the other hand, both seem to be available via Amazon:

- [Nuclear Strike](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000038ABM)
- [Fury 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FZAQKY)

Comment: Your HotU link is broken, (missing the t off .net)